# Java Json выгрузка разных полей

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть объект с несколькими полями который отправляется как `Json` запрос на сервер.

Допустим есть два разных `Json` запроса на сервер: 1 добавление данных, 2 обновление данных.

Как сделать так, чтоб при разных `Json` запросах отправлялись разные поля одного объекта?

Например:

- при добавлении отправлять только поле `name`
- при обновлении отправлять поля `yandexId` и `name`

  ```
  public class CampaignDataTest implements Serializable {

      private long id;
      private long yandexId;
      private String name;

     //Гетеры и сеттеры

  }
  ```

Comment: Вы можете отправлять либо как PATCH/PUT/POST разные виды "запросов". Это 1 из вариантов.
Для дальнейшего обсуждения привидите пример ваших запросов и, по возможности контроллера/сервиса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если пользуешься Jackson

Заводим класс с интерфейсами. Ими мы будем помечать поля. Если один интерфейс расширяет другой, он включит в Json все поля помеченные предком.

```
public final class Views {
    public interface Name {}
    public interface IdName extends Name{}
    public interface FullUserInfo extends IdName {} 
}
```

Потом в классе помечаем поля @JsonView

```
   @JsonView(Views.FullUserInfo.class)  
   private long id;
   @JsonView(Views.IdName.class)
   private long yandexId;
   @JsonView(Views.Name.class)
   private String name;
```

В контроллере помечаем методы аннотациями

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
   @PutMapping("/")
   @JsonView(Views.Name.class)
   public User addUser() {...}

   @PatchMapping("/")
   @JsonView(Views.IdName.class)
   public User updateUser() {...}
}
```

Теперь после запроса с фронтенда по одному адресу (н.р http://localhost:8080/user/) но разными методами (Put и Patch) будут вызываться разные методы контроллера. А в ответ будут уходить json с полями помеченными нужным интерфейсом. Т.е метод addUser() вернет json вида {"name":"someName"}, а updateUser() {"name":"someName","yandexId":"1234567890"}

Comment: `Как сделать так, чтоб при разных Json запросах отправлялись разные поля одного объекта?`

Comment: Ну addUser будет `@PutMapping` а updateUser, будет `@PatchMapping`. А в результате в ответ будут уходить разные jsonы.

Comment: я java не знаю, и не знаю, что такое `@PutMapping`, но и у вас в ответе нету этого `@PutMapping` или какого другого пояснения, как  по разному сериализовать объект. То есть вы отвечаете на какой то вопрос, но, мне кажется, не на тот, что задает автор вопроса.

Comment: @Marat. А зачем такая сложность с интерфейсами? Можно точно также просто делать `return new User(){setId(10); setName("name");} ` Для каждого метода, в зависимости от типа запроса, отправлять разные данные

Comment: @dred Так вроде принято делать в Spring. Если у объекта будет 20 полей, то удобнее одной аннотацией определить возвращаемые поля, чем создавать новый объект, занулять поля, а в итоге передать полный json. Вот например на хабре статья https://habr.com/ru/post/307392/